# segmentation fault when passing a double pointer in a recursive function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, quadtree

I have this simple code that is supposed to create a quadtree.

```
/* here is my quadtree struct */

typedef struct QuadTree {
    AABB *boundry;
    Point **points;

    struct QuadTree** NW;
    struct QuadTree** NE;
    struct QuadTree** SW;
    struct QuadTree** SE;

} QuadTree;

/* here is a function that creates new quadtree */

QuadTree *QuadTree_new(AABB *boundry) {
    QuadTree *qt = (QuadTree *)malloc(sizeof(QuadTree));
    qt->NE = NULL;
    qt->NW = NULL;
    qt->SE = NULL;
    qt->SW = NULL;

    qt->boundry = boundry;

    qt->points = (Point **)malloc(sizeof(Point*) * QT_NODE_CAPACITY);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < QT_NODE_CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        qt->points[i] = NULL;
    }
    

    return qt;
}

/* here is a recursive function where I create multiple quadtree linked to each other */

bool QuadTree_insert(QuadTree **root, Point *point) {
    QuadTree **child; 
    if (!AABB_cotains_point((*root)->boundry, point)) {
        return false;  
    }
    
    int points_size = QuadTree_points_size((*root)->points);
    
    if ((*root)->NW == NULL){
        if (points_size < QT_NODE_CAPACITY ) {
            (*root)->points[points_size] = point;
            return true;
        }else if((*root)->boundry->halfDimension >= QT_NODE_RES){

            root = QuadTree_subdivide(&(*root));
        }
    }

    child = (*root)->NW;
    if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}
    child = (*root)->NE;
    if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}
    child = (*root)->SW;
    if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}
    child = (*root)->SE;
    if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}

    return false;
}

QuadTree **QuadTree_subdivide(QuadTree **root) {
    float halfDim = (*root)->boundry->halfDimension / 2;
    // North West
    Point *nw_p = Point_new((*root)->boundry->center->x - halfDim, (*root)->boundry->center->y + halfDim);
    QuadTree *q1= QuadTree_new(AABB_new(nw_p, halfDim));
    (*root)->NW = (QuadTree **)malloc(sizeof(QuadTree*));
    (*root)->NW = &q1;

    // North East
    Point *ne_p = Point_new((*root)->boundry->center->x + halfDim, (*root)->boundry->center->y + halfDim);
    QuadTree *q2= QuadTree_new(AABB_new(ne_p, halfDim));
    (*root)->NE = (QuadTree **)malloc(sizeof(QuadTree*));
    (*root)->NE = &q2;

    // South West
    Point *sw_p = Point_new((*root)->boundry->center->x - halfDim, (*root)->boundry->center->y - halfDim);
    QuadTree *q3= QuadTree_new(AABB_new(sw_p, halfDim));
    (*root)->SW = (QuadTree **)malloc(sizeof(QuadTree*));
    (*root)->SW = &q3;

    // South East
    Point *se_p = Point_new((*root)->boundry->center->x + halfDim, (*root)->boundry->center->y - halfDim);
    QuadTree *q4= QuadTree_new(AABB_new(se_p, halfDim));
    (*root)->SE = (QuadTree **)malloc(sizeof(QuadTree*));
    (*root)->SE =&q4;

    return &(*root);
}
```

I believe my error is in the above part of the code, however I added the below to make it compilable.

```
#define QT_NODE_CAPACITY (1)
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE (1024)
#define QT_NODE_RES (8)

/* here is a point struct */
typedef struct Point {
    float x;
    float y;
} Point;

/* here a square data struct */
typedef struct AABB {
    Point *center;
    float halfDimension;    
} AABB;

/* create a new point */
Point *Point_new(float x, float y) {
    Point *p = (Point *)malloc(sizeof(Point));
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    return p;
}

/* create a new square */
AABB *AABB_new(Point *center, float halfDimension) {
    AABB *aabb = (AABB *)malloc(sizeof(AABB));
    aabb->center = center;
    aabb->halfDimension = halfDimension;
    return aabb;
}

/* check if a square contains a point */
bool AABB_cotains_point(AABB *boundry, Point *point) { 
    if (point->x < boundry->center->x - boundry->halfDimension || point->x > boundry->center->x + boundry->halfDimension) {
        return false;
    }

    if (point->y < boundry->center->y - boundry->halfDimension || point->y > boundry->center->y + boundry->halfDimension) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/* how many points in an array of points */
int QuadTree_points_size(Point *points[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < QT_NODE_CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        if (points[i] == NULL) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Specify Inital Axis Aligned Bounding Box \n");
    printf("Center: \n");
    float x, y;
    printf("X: ");
    scanf("%e", &x);
    printf("Y: ");
    scanf("%e", &y);
    
    float hd;
    printf("Half Dimension: ");
    scanf("%e", &hd);

    Point *center = Point_new(x, y);
    AABB *boundry = AABB_new(center, hd);
    printf("Quad Tree Boundry\n");
    AABB_print(boundry);

    QuadTree *qt = NULL;
    qt = (QuadTree *)malloc(sizeof(QuadTree *));
    qt = QuadTree_new(boundry);
    
    int count;
    printf("Enter Number of Points to insert: ");
    scanf("%d", &count); 
    int i = 0;
    struct Point* p[count];
    int psize = count;
    while (count-- > 0) {
        i++;
        printf("Point %d\n", i);
        float x, y;
        printf("X: ");
        scanf("%e", &x);
        printf("Y: ");
        scanf("%e", &y);
        p[i] = Point_new(x, y);
        printf("Point: ");
        Point_print(p[i]);
    }

        //insert points
        int j=0;
        while(j++ != psize) {
            if (!QuadTree_insert(&qt, p[j])) {
                        printf("Point Outside boundry. Not Inserted\n");
                 }else{
                        printf("Point inserted successfully\n");
             }
            }

    return 0;
}
```

when I call the function QuadTree_insert it works only once then when it is recalled again it throws a segmentation fault either when it reaches AABB_cotains_point or  QuadTree_points_size and I don't understand why this happens, could someone please help.

My code wasn't throwing segmentation fault when I wasn't using a double pointer. However without the double pointer I lose reference of the complete quadtree list. therefore I added the double pointer SE SW NE NW quadtree structs

Comment: This address that you store here: `(*root)->NW = &q1;` is on stack and is only valid during the time `QuadTree_subdivide()` is active.

Comment: I needed NW to be a double pointer because when it wasn't, I wasn't able to retrieve the whole quadtree. Therefore, I had to do this `(*root)->NW = &q1;`. do you have any suggestions for how I could assign the value

Comment: The code snippet cannot be compiled. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre].

Comment: `QuadTree_subdivide()` also has a memory leak. It sets `(*root)->NW` to the result of a call to `malloc` and then immediately sets `(*root)->NW` to point somewhere completely different (and as @500-InternalServerError points out, somewhere that will not be valid when the function returns).

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using double pointers for those `NW`, `NE`, `SW` and `SE` members.

Comment: You can not just add an `*` to get the value of the pointers outside the `struct`. Sure, you can use as many levels of addressing as you want or need, but this things must be carefully constructed.

Please post something compilable.

Comment: I updated the code to make it compilable

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. In `Quadtree_insert()` I didn't check if `(*root)->NE == NULL` before the below lines

```
child = (*root)->NW;
if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}
child = (*root)->NE;
if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}
child = (*root)->SW;
if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}
child = (*root)->SE;
if (QuadTree_insert(&(*child), point)){ return true;}

return false
```